# RabbitMQ Free disk space is insufficient

Tags: rabbitmq

I try to add a message to a queue with Java client but rabbitmq keeps me blocked.
[image]

Official documentation says at https://www.rabbitmq.com/disk-alarms.html :

> When free disk space drops below a configured limit (50 MB by default), an alarm will be triggered and all producers will be blocked.

My disc space looks like this
[image]

So, I set the disk space in the config file:

```
disk_free_limit.absolute = 1000MB
```

but it does not increment it. Disk space still looks like above.
[image]

Also log file says this:

```
2022-01-17 16:17:34.538000+03:00 [info] <0.399.0> Enabling free disk space monitoring
2022-01-17 16:17:34.538000+03:00 [info] <0.399.0> Disk free limit set to 1000MB
2022-01-17 16:17:34.844000+03:00 [info] <0.399.0> Free disk space is insufficient. Free bytes: 40. Limit: 1000000000
2022-01-17 16:17:34.844000+03:00 [info] <0.223.0> Running boot step code_server_cache defined by app rabbit
2022-01-17 16:17:34.844000+03:00 [warning] <0.395.0> disk resource limit alarm set on node 'rabbit@BLG2A-V1-BB0268'.
2022-01-17 16:17:34.844000+03:00 [warning] <0.395.0> 
2022-01-17 16:17:34.844000+03:00 [warning] <0.395.0> **********************************************************
2022-01-17 16:17:34.844000+03:00 [warning] <0.395.0> *** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***
2022-01-17 16:17:34.844000+03:00 [warning] <0.395.0> **********************************************************
2022-01-17 16:17:34.844000+03:00 [warning] <0.395.0>
```

How can I increment disk space?

My setup:

```
OS: Windows 10
RabbitMQ: 3.9.12
Erlang/OTP: 24.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed RabbitMQ version to 3.9.11. Now, it is fixed.

[image]

I guess, version 3.9.12 was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The alarm is telling you that *your server* only has 50MB of space left on the disk which RabbitMQ is trying to write to.

The `disk_free_limit` setting doesn't control how much disk is *allocated*, it controls how much disk is *expected* - if you set it to 1000MB, the alarm will be triggered as soon as there is only 1000MB left, rather than waiting until there is only 50MB left.

Making more disk space available is the same as it would be for any other program:

- Delete other things that are using up your disk space - e.g. make sure log files are compressed and deleted after a certain amount of time
- Configure RabbitMQ to use a different disk or partition, if you already have one that's bigger
- Install a larger disk if it's a physical host, or allocate a larger disk image if it's a VM

Answer (score 2):

This issue will be fixed in 3.9.13

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/pull/3970